# How to run multiple Webpages on same test class

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, testng

I want to automate two different website so how to run multiple URL.
Currently I am creating one config.prop and from there it is running the test.
now i want two webpage to run

Comment: You want to run the same test on two different sites?. Also, you must add the related snippet

Comment: I want to run another test with another site as well but i want to write in same project means i dont want separate and fresh project, I just want both site and test should be maintained in same project

Answer (score 1):

There are situations where you want to run multiple tests with same or different browsers at the same time. In such cases, use “parallel” attribute in testng.xml to accomplish parallel test execution in TestNG.

To accomplish that create tesNG.xml file if you have not created yet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
<test name="FirefoxTest">
 <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
 <classes>
 <class name="your class name with package" />
 </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="IETest">
 <parameter name="browser" value="ie" />
 <classes>
 <class name="your class name with package" />
 </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Here parallel = tests with run your tests parallel and maintain thread count.

In your test java file you need to utilize this parameters,

```
public class YourTestClass {
public WebDriver driver;

  @Parameters("browser")
  @BeforeClass
  // Passing Browser parameter from TestNG xml
  public void beforeTest(String browser) {

  // If the browser is Firefox, then do this
  if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
      // gecodriver path set up
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();

  // If browser is IE, then do this   
  }else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) { 
      // setting up the path for IEDriver
      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "server path");
      driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  } 

  // Doesn't the browser type, lauch the Website
  driver.get("your URL"); 
  }

  // Once Before method is completed, Test method will start
  @Test 
  public void yourTestMethod() {
  // method implementation
  }  

  @AfterClass public void afterTest() {
     driver.quit();
  }

}
```

Run the test as you would normally run any other TestNG test based on a suite XML. Do the following:

1. In intellij menu, go to Run > Edit Configurations.
2. Click the "+" icon (or Add new configuration)
3. Select TestNG from the list.
4. (Optional) Name your run configuration.
5. Choose Suite, select your testng.xml file in the resources folder, and hit OK.
6. Select your configuration and hit the run button.

Tip: In IntelliJ IDEA, you can also run the test by right-clicking the testng.xml file and then Run.